# How do I sort by a specific date range in my http call?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, date

I've got an array of objects coming from my API.  There are 8 properties I'm sorting by, including one which is a date.

My sorting guidelines are as follows:

1 - If any of the values are false, or if the updated date is over a month old from today's date, I want these items to show up first on my page.

2 - If all of the values are true, but the update date is between two weeks old and a month old, I want these items to show up second on my page.

3 -If everything is true and the date is within two weeks of the current date, these items should show up last on my page.

1 is sorting correctly and coming first, but 2 is showing up mixed with 1 rather than coming second. 3 is working correctly and coming last.

Here is the code I wrote to try and get this sorted:

```
Date = new Date();
Date2 = new Date();
fourWeeksAgo = this.Date.setDate(this.Date.getDate() - 30);
TwoWeeksAgo = this.Date2.setDate(this.Date2.getDate() - 14);
dateMinusMonth = this.datepipe.transform(this.fourWeeksAgo, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
dateMinusTwoWeeks = this.datepipe.transform(this.TwoWeeksAgo, 'MM-dd-yyyy');

baseurl: 'http://dr0-hlp-07/api/';

  deleteMachine(id: number): Observable<void> {
  return this.httpClient.delete<void>('http://dr0-hlp-07/api/PCIMachines/' + id)};

  getPciInfo(): Observable <Ipcidata[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Ipcidata[]>('http://dr0-hlp-07/api/PCIMachines').pipe(
      map(results => results.sort(( a, b ) => {
        const latestDate = this.datepipe.transform(b.UpdatedDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
        if (this.dateMinusMonth > latestDate
          || !b.AMStatus
          || !b.BLStatus
          || !b.FirewallRuleStatus
          || !b.FirewallContentStatus
          || !b.SCCMStatus
          || !b.MSBaselineStatus
          || !b.USBStatus
          ) {
          return 1;
        } else if (
          this.dateMinusMonth < latestDate
          && this.dateMinusTwoWeeks >= latestDate
          && b.AMStatus
          && b.BLStatus
          && b.FirewallRuleStatus
          && b.FirewallContentStatus
          && b.SCCMStatus
          && b.MSBaselineStatus
          && b.USBStatus
          ) {return 0; } else {return -1; }
    })));
```

Here's what my object looks like:

```
export interface Ipcidata {
id: Int16Array;
hostname: string;
AMStatus: boolean;
BLStatus: boolean;
FirewallRuleStatus: boolean;
FirewallContentStatus: boolean;
SCCMStatus: boolean;
MSBaselineStatus: boolean;
UpdatedDate: Date;
USBStatus: boolean;
}
```

I know I'm probably royally screwing this up, I'm new to all of this. Can someone tell me why this isn't sorting correctly at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you why it's not sorting correctly, it's because you only evaluate `b` and when it's in the case 2, you tell "don't change the order".

I answered your question. Joke aside, I guess you also want to know how to solve this ;) well you need to add much more cases, you tried to simplify, but oversimplified it! Actually:

- case 1 must be before every time
- case 2 must be consistently after case 1 and consistently before general case
- the logical contrary of "every value is true" is conveniently "at least one is false"

Try with:

```
//UPDATE: changed dates format
dateMinusMonth = this.datepipe.transform(this.fourWeeksAgo, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
dateMinusTwoWeeks = this.datepipe.transform(this.TwoWeeksAgo, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

//unchanged code

    return this.httpClient.get<Ipcidata[]>('http://dr0-hlp-07/api/PCIMachines').pipe(
      map(results => results.sort(( a, b ) => {
        //UPDATE: changed dates format
        const latestDateA = this.datepipe.transform(a.UpdatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        const latestDateB = this.datepipe.transform(b.UpdatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        const everyTrueInA = a.AMStatus && a.BLStatus && a.FirewallRuleStatus && a.FirewallContentStatus && a.SCCMStatus && a.MSBaselineStatus && a.USBStatus;
        const everyTrueInB = b.AMStatus && b.BLStatus && b.FirewallRuleStatus && b.FirewallContentStatus && b.SCCMStatus && b.MSBaselineStatus && b.USBStatus;
        //cases 1 and 3 -> always first or last
        //UPDATES: this.dateMinusMonth > latestDateA  AND  this.dateMinusTwoWeeks <= latestDateB
        if (this.dateMinusMonth > latestDateA || !everyTrueInA || (this.dateMinusTwoWeeks <= latestDateB && everyTrueInB)) {
          return -1;
        }
        else if (this.dateMinusMonth > latestDateB || !everyTrueInB || (this.dateMinusTwoWeeks <= latestDateA && everyTrueInA)) {
          return 1;
        }
        //case 2 -> we know now that neither a or b is case 1 or 3, just needs to come before general case
        else if (this.dateMinusMonth < latestDateA && this.dateMinusTwoWeeks >= latestDateA && everyTrueInA) {
          return -1;
        }
        else if (this.dateMinusMonth < latestDateB && this.dateMinusTwoWeeks >= latestDateB && everyTrueInB) {
          return 1;
        }
        //general case (not supposed to happen with these rules)
        return 0;
    })));
```

**UPDATE:** Actually there were other things wrong that I overlooked because I didn't pay enough attention to details:

- Your date formatting is a bit wrong, comparing string dates will work only because in ASCII order, number chars are ordered, but it's not really the proper way, however if you want it to work across the end of the year / beginning of a new one, always use `'yyyy-MM-dd'`
- Some of the date tests were other way round. A date is more recent than another when it's greater (for cases 1 and 3).

See example snippet:

```js
const dateMinusMonth = '2019-08-17';
const dateMinusTwoWeeks = '2019-09-03';

let results = [
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-09-02', AMStatus: true, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 2' },
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-09-15', AMStatus: true, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 3' },
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-07-18', AMStatus: true, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 1' },
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-09-16', AMStatus: true, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 3' },
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-09-01', AMStatus: true, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 2' },
  { UpdatedDate: '2019-08-20', AMStatus: false, BLStatus: true, FirewallRuleStatus: true, FirewallContentStatus: true, SCCMStatus: true, MSBaselineStatus: true, USBStatus: true, test: 'Case 1' },
];

results = results.sort(( a, b ) => {
  const latestDateA = /*this.datepipe.transform(*/a.UpdatedDate/*, 'MM-dd-yyyy')*/;
  const latestDateB = /*this.datepipe.transform(*/b.UpdatedDate/*, 'MM-dd-yyyy')*/;
  const everyTrueInA = a.AMStatus && a.BLStatus && a.FirewallRuleStatus && a.FirewallContentStatus && a.SCCMStatus && a.MSBaselineStatus && a.USBStatus;
  const everyTrueInB = b.AMStatus && b.BLStatus && b.FirewallRuleStatus && b.FirewallContentStatus && b.SCCMStatus && b.MSBaselineStatus && b.USBStatus;
  
  //cases 1 and 3 -> always first or last
  if (/*this.*/dateMinusMonth > latestDateA || !everyTrueInA || (/*this.*/dateMinusTwoWeeks <= latestDateB && everyTrueInB)) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (/*this.*/dateMinusMonth > latestDateB || !everyTrueInB || (/*this.*/dateMinusTwoWeeks <= latestDateA && everyTrueInA)) {
    return 1;
  }
  //case 2 -> we know now that neither a or b is case 1 or 3, just needs to come before general case
  else if (/*this.*/dateMinusMonth < latestDateA && /*this.*/dateMinusTwoWeeks >= latestDateA && everyTrueInA) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (/*this.*/dateMinusMonth < latestDateB && /*this.*/dateMinusTwoWeeks >= latestDateB && everyTrueInB) {
    return 1;
  }
  //general case (not supposed to happen with these rules)
  return 0;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: This seems to have got me close to the answer!  For some reason case 2 is now coming last, but they are grouped up at least, which wasn't happening before.  

Thank you for taking the time to help me with this, marking you as the answer, if you could explain why case 2 is coming last that would be awesome.